# (PrimePush) com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, primepush

I am new to PrimePush and want to try it out. I followed this [tutorial](http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/howto_blogs/1298-using_primefaces_primepush_with_tomcat_7)

 However, when I run the register.xhtml file, I hit the error of *com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.* 
 These are jar that I have

- atmosphere-compat-jbossweb-1.0.1
- atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.0.1
- atmostphere-compat-tomcat7-1.0.1
- atmostphere-runtime-1.0.1
- primefaces-3.4.2
- slf4j-api-1.7.2
- slf4j-simple-1.7.2
- JSF 2.1 (Mojarra 2.1.6)

I am using **tomcat7** and **jre7**

This is **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Test1</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8080</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.HeaderBroadcasterCache</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcastFilterClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>bean.PushBean</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is **register.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">  
        <h:outputText id="out" value="#{pushBean.count}"
    styleClass="ui-widget display" />  
        <br />  
        <p:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{pushBean.increment}" />  
    </h:form>  

    <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />  

     <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleMessage(data) {
                $('.display').html(data);
            }          
    </script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This is **PushBean.java**

```
package Bean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.primefaces.push.PushContext;
import org.primefaces.push.PushContextFactory;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PushBean implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public PushBean() {
}
private int count;

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public synchronized void increment() {
    count++;
    PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
    pushContext.push("/counter", String.valueOf(count));
}
}
```

From this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes/), it says

Many reasons causing this “ResourceConfig” error message. Few solutions that i know :

- com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages doesn’t exist in your web.xml.
- com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages included a resource that doesn’t include any jersey services. In above case, "com.mkyong.rest” doesn’t contains any jersey services.

So I am thinking that **could it be bean.PushBean in web.xml that is wrong**?

However, I don't know how to change it (if bean.PushBean is a problem). From eclipse project explorer, the PushBean.java path is Java Resources -> src -> Bean ->PushBean.java

Please help me find the solution. Thanks in advance.